# Cannot install Leopard (Mac OS X 10.5) on PowerPC Mac

Tags: install, mac-pro, leopard, powerpc

I have an old Power Mac running Tiger (Mac OS X 10.4.11). It is a Dual 2.3 GHz Power-PC G5 with 8 GB RAM. I have it running Tiger since that is the last OS that supports Classic (OS 9) (via Rosetta) and the kids had many Classic programs and games that they like.

As far as I know, Leopard (Mac OS X 10.5) is the last OS that can be run on this machine. As it has 2 internal HD slots, I installed a 2 TB SSD in the empty one in order to install Leopard on it. The SSD is partitioned into 2 discs, 1 TB each, and formatted according to the Apple Partition Map (not GUID).

When trying to install Leopard OS from an original DVD, and choosing one of the SSD drives, the installation starts and stalls after a few seconds. The whole machine freezes, and I have to do a hard reset.

I also have an original Mac OS X 10.5.6 disc (© Apple 2009) and when I try to install from it, I get a window saying "This Operating System cannot be installed in this Mac" (!!!).

I then created a bootable USB flash memory with the iso image of Mac OS X 10.5.6 downloaded from the Internet. My Mac does not see it, even if I boot while pressing the Option key.

So I have not been able to install Leopard on a machine which is supposed to be able to run Leopard. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to tell us exactly what this DVD has written on it. Some DVDs were specific to particular Mac models, and won't work on any other Mac. You also need to describe the process of downloading an "iso" and how you made the bootable drive. 
But -- why do you want to install Leopard anyway? You lose Classic mode (NB, Not Rosetta, that's for Intel Macs running PPC code). And it's not like you need to keep up-to-date.

Comment: @benwiggy: Yes, not Rosetta but the Classic emulator, sorry, I confused the names. The first disc was the original installation disc. The second (10.5.6) does not specify if it is for a particular model, but it may have well been for a MacBook Pro. The iso image was downloaded from the Internet, and I used Disk Utility to set this iso file as source and the USB flash memory as target. Leopard was for the second internal drive (keeping Tiger and Classic on the first). I assumed that Leopard would give me an advantage over Tiger; but I might as well just keep Tiger and forget the rest. Thanks.